# Google Maps Geocoding Error with Django

Tags: python, django, google-maps, simplejson

After hours of trying to figure out the problem here, I've given up. I am using http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2241/ (saved in myproject/custom.py) to query Google and return the co-ordinates of the location. The beginning of my function is:

```
def locQuery(location **kwargs):
    """
    This function returns a queryset of locations based on a Google Geocode
    lookup and other parameters
    """
    q = GoogleLatLng()
    query = MyModel.objects.none()
    try:
        q.requestLatLngJSON(location)
    except:
        return query
    # Do something based on kwargs #
```

However, I get the following error intermittently:

```
>>> locQuery('York')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/../myproject/custom.py", line 85, in parseResults
    self.results = json.loads(buff)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 360, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 376, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting object: line 37 column 8 (char 1133)
[]
```

The following is an example of the code working as it should:

```
>>> locQuery('York')
[]
```

Any help at all would be wonderful.

EDIT:
So I've finally decided that the snippet itself is faulty. I am now using the python code available on http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/index.html#ParsingJSON to perform my Geocoding queries...